# Update Boolean field and Integer fields from Django view

Tags: python-3.x, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, django-views

Can someone please point me in the right direction here. I have a quiz app where I want to implement some user progress objects. I have a QuizResult model which foreignkeys to user, quiz and lesson. What I want is to be able to update a couple of fields: score (integer field) and complete (boolean field) from my views.py function. when I try to update these fields from my frontend I get a no errors, but the object shows complete and score fields as null.

Here is my model:

```
class QuizResult(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="results", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name="results", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, null=True, blank=True, related_name="results", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and my view.py function:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def post_progress(request, pk):
    data = request.data
    score = data.get('score')
    complete = data.get('complete') 

    quiz = Quiz.objects.get(pk=pk)

    user_progress = QuizResult.objects.create(quiz=quiz, score=score, complete=complete, student=request.user)

    serializer = QuizResultSerializer(user_progress, data=data)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This means your request did not receive `score` and `complete` fields, make sure you send them, you can try `assert score != None`

Comment: @Mohamed Hamza ok is the syntax correct in my views.py function to accept a boolean ?

Comment: Yes, It's right

Comment: Sorry where do I need to add ```assert score != None```

Comment: Put it before `score = data.get('score')` we just need to check if your request receives a `score` or not. but what I can't understand is that you said `What I want is to be able to update a couple of fields: score ...` but in your `views.py` you are creating a new `QuizResult` object not updating an existing one!

Comment: I created a new model just for the users progress score on each quiz taken. Im getting error ```UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score' referenced before assignment```

Comment: My bad, I meant `After` not `before`, anyway could you show me how you send your request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242717/discussion-between-mark-mckeon-and-mohamed-hamza).